# What is the point of the inc variable in the PCG RNG?

Tags: random

From [this code](http://www.pcg-random.org/download.html):

```c
// *Really* minimal PCG32 code / (c) 2014 M.E. O'Neill / pcg-random.org
// Licensed under Apache License 2.0 (NO WARRANTY, etc. see website)

typedef struct { uint64_t state;  uint64_t inc; } pcg32_random_t;

uint32_t pcg32_random_r(pcg32_random_t* rng)
{
    uint64_t oldstate = rng->state;
    // Advance internal state
    rng->state = oldstate * 6364136223846793005ULL + (rng->inc|1);
    // Calculate output function (XSH RR), uses old state for max ILP
    uint32_t xorshifted = ((oldstate >> 18u) ^ oldstate) >> 27u;
    uint32_t rot = oldstate >> 59u;
    return (xorshifted >> rot) | (xorshifted << ((-rot) & 31));
}
```

What is the point of `rng->inc`? it is never written to as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it’s a seed – stream selector, to be precise. Take a look at the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/imneme/pcg-c-basic), especially the `pcg32_srandom_r` function:

```
// pcg32_srandom(initstate, initseq)
// pcg32_srandom_r(rng, initstate, initseq):
//     Seed the rng.  Specified in two parts, state initializer and a
//     sequence selection constant (a.k.a. stream id)

void pcg32_srandom_r(pcg32_random_t* rng, uint64_t initstate, uint64_t initseq)
{
    rng->state = 0U;
    rng->inc = (initseq << 1u) | 1u;
    pcg32_random_r(rng);
    rng->state += initstate;
    pcg32_random_r(rng);
}
```

There’s more about streams on [the PCG website](http://www.pcg-random.org/rng-basics.html).

Comment: Ah I see, so it's in case you want a few different PRN sequences, but want to refer to them as #1, #2, #3, etc... Thanks!